# Can you assign multiple strings to the same variable on the same line?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble writing a program that asks for your birthday and then the user can confirm if their inputted birthday is true or false (yes or no), however, I want to be able to accept an answer of "yes" if it was spelt with an accidental capital visa Veras for "no"

For example if I were to input "Yes" instead of "yes" as an answer to whether or not the correct birthday is being displayed in the console, the computer would still accept that as an answer as the word is still spelt correctly.

So in that case, I am trying to understand if I can assign multiple ways of spelling "yes" to one variable so I don't have to type all the ways you can write the word "yes" and assign it too different variables.

Here is what I have tried for my code:

```
answer_YES = 'Yes' or "yes"
answer_NO = 'No' 

Name = input("What's your name? ")
Last_Name = input("What's your last name? ")
print("\nHello,", Name, Last_Name + "!")

num1 = float(input("Give me one number: "))
num2 = float(input("Give me a better number: "))

print("\nHere is your Summary:")
print(int(num1), '+', int(num2), '=', int(num1 + num2))

BD = input("\nOK, now give me your birthday m/d/y: ")
print("Is this your birthday?", '"' + BD + '"' "\n\nCorrect? (Yes) Incorrect? (No)\n")
answer = input("Answer: ")

#Using Boolean Expressions

if answer == answer_YES:
    print("Awesome! Thank you", Name)
```

Comment: `'Yes' or "yes"` just evaluates to `'Yes'`. You could assign a _sequence_ of values, like a list or tuple, or just canonicalise the user's input to e.g. lowercase for comparison.

Comment: Rather than try to account for all variations of `Yes, yEs, yeS, yes` etc., match it to a lower case version of their answer. `if answer.lower() == 'yes':`

Comment: `answer.lower() in {'yes' 'y'}`

Comment: if answer.upper() == 'yes'.swapcase() also works

Comment: lol... @rv.kvetch why? I feel like that's a fairly obfuscated way to write "YES"

Comment: haha, yeah I guess they are both different ways of writing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is all about the yes spelling (Yes or YEs or YES ...)
you can have

```
anser_YES = 'yes'
```

then in the validation you do something like

```
if answer.lower() == answer_YES
```

otherway if you want make multilang input accept you can use list of accepted answers, so
instead of

```
answer_YES = 'yes'
```

do

```
answer_YES = ['yes', 'oui', 'Yeeeeeessss']
```

then to test the true response do

```
if answer in answer_YES:
```

i wish this was helpful for you

Comment: A set would be better than a list for thiss use case

Comment: Or mix the two! `if answer.lower() in answer_YES:` with only lower case versions in `answer_YES`

Comment: @BeRT2me just because sets are  o(1) to check if an item is in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in keyword

```
answer_YES = ("Yes", "yes")
if answer in answer_YES:
    do_something()
```

or use

```
if answer.lower() == "yes":
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to assign multiple values to a variable.

If you just want a simple check, I would use the lower() function to make the strings match without worrying about capitalization.  An alternative would be to search for it in a set.

```
answer_YES = "yes"

...

if answer.lower() == answer_YES:
    print("Awesome! Thank you", Name)
```

or

```
answer_YES = {"Yes", "yes"} 

...

if answer in answer_YES:
    print("Awesome! Thank you", Name)
```